# Modifying an object right before serialization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `C` which must use the GPU on the parent process, but only the CPU on the child processes.

Since `C` is sent to the child processes through serialization, to be extra safe, I decided to add `__reduce__` to `C` so that I can modify a flag right before serialization:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    """
    This is just to avoid that we use the gpu on subprocesses.
    """
    p = self.copy(shallow=True)
    p._cpu_only = True

    return _dummy_rebuild, (p,)
```

This doesn't work because of an infinite recursion. I see two solutions:

1. remove `__reduce__` from `p`
2. return the attributes of `p` and rebuild from them

I think option 1 is preferable because it doesn't depend on the internals of the class.

The only problem is that I can't remove `__reduce__`. Is there a way?

Comment: ...if you remove `__reduce__`, how would `p` be serialized? Does whichever serializer you're using have a default mechanism in place that can handle `C` instances? Not that removing `__reduce__` from an instance is possible anyway.

Comment: @Aran-Fey My class is already serializable. I added `__reduce__` just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> to remove `__reduce__` from `p`, because the `__reduce__` method only exists in your class and not on each individual instance. You can remove it from *all* instances by removing it from the class, but you can't remove it only from select instances.

<sup>(*Technically it depends on the serializer. Depending on *how* the serializer checks for the existence of a `__reduce__` method, it may or may not be possible to trick it into thinking that `p` doesn't have one. But it's definitely not a good idea to do that.)</sup>

---

Your only/best option is therefore to rewrite the `__reduce__` method so that it doesn't return an instance of your class.

Comment: Is it also impossible to *add* a method to selected instances?

Comment: @Kiuhnm Yes. It's as simple as assigning a function to an attribute of the instance: `instance.new_method = some_function` (though that function won't get the implicit `self` argument). If your method needs `self`, you can do `instance.new_method = some_function.__get__(instance)`.

Comment: Also, if I add `__reduce__` by hand in `__init__` I can then remove it because it's been added to the instances themselves, right?

Comment: @Kiuhnm Yes. But that will only have an effect if your serializer checks for the existance of `__reduce__` directly on the instance, for example with `if hasattr(instance, '__reduce__'):`. If it checks the _class_, then that won't help. And in either case it's ugly code.

Comment: Yep, I agree. I'll go with option 2. Thanks.